# C Programming: Why printf Format Specifier %s Is Invalid For The Number "123"?

Tags: c, printf

I am quite a C programming newbie.

With answers for other question, I could understand the term "character" could point to vary elements; e.g. letters and numbers.

I am regarding "string" as characters.

Then, please take a look at the lines below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int numbers = 123;
    printf("%c%s\n", "N", numbers); 
}
```

When I tried to compile this code, error messages were displayed and compiling failed.

The textbook "The C Programming Language" page 13 says like below about printf format specifiers;

> "`%c` for character"
>
> "`%s` for character string".

**First Question:**

Although "N" is a character, why is `%c` specifier invalid?

**Second Question:**

Although the value of variable "numbers" is "123", they are numbers, which are included in the character.

I have thought characters equal "string."

Then, although I have used %s for "123", why is it invalid?

I know my code will work, if I revise them like one below:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int numbers = 123;
    printf("%s%d\n", "N", numbers); 
}
```

but I would want to understand why the code above is invalid.

Comment: The `"N"` is *not* a character. It is a *string literal* consisting of one character (and the terminating null character, which is implicit).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please do not add tons of unrelated tags. That is considered spamming. If you have problems with C standard functions there is no need to add `bash` or `unix` tags.

Comment: @user3121023 `'N'` is an `int`, not a `char`.  In particular, `sizeof('N')` is not 1, which it would be if it were a character.  It is the integer value of the character `N`, but not a `char`.

Comment: `main()` is not valid in C for quite some time. This is one of the anachronisms in your textbook. You should always write `int main(void)`.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thank you for you suggestion. I've understood  there is no need to add many tag!

Comment: @TomKarzes Hello! I have noticed many article's sample code are using `int main()`. I 've understood just `main()` is not preferable. Thank you.

Comment: @CaptainCookie You should use `int main(void)`.  Leaving out the `void` will probably work with most implementations, but it's not guaranteed to work.  Leaving out the `int` results in an implicit `int` return value, but it's bad form.

Comment: @TomKarzes I will do some research about how containg void works. Thank you for giving additional information!

Comment: @CaptainCookie Declaring a function with a `(void)` argument list just means the function takes no arguments.  For legacy reasons, declaring a function with an empty `()` argument list means the arguments are unspecified.  You should never use an empty `()` argument list in a function declaration.

Comment: @TomKarzes Today, I have learned how to implement not main functions, which I declared with () though, but I will also always do them with (void). My textbook seems to be the traditional one, so getting current common ways helps me a lot. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The instruction

```
printf("%c%s\n", "N", numbers);
```

contains two mistakes.

1. Format specifier `%c` expects that a single character is passed. The way we define a character constant in C is using single quotes `'N'`.
   By using double quotes `"N"` you are using a *syntactic sugar way* C offers to represent a string, that is an array of characters *closed* by the string terminator `'\0'`
2. `123` is an integer, and like you correctly wrote the `%d` format specifier is expected

Talking about the last mistake, you gave an original interpretation

> Although the value of variabale "numbers" is "123", they are numbers, which are included in the character.
>
> I have thought characters equal "string."
>
> Then, although I have used %s for "123", why is it invalid?

Though it is obviously a wrong interpretation, I find it *interesting* and it deserves an explanation.

Is `123` a string, that is a sequence of characters? Sure it is! But it is a string within the **source code**. The compiler will parse this sequence of characters, will recognize an integer, and will make sure that this value is stored within a memory location containing an integer. In most modern computers it will translate into a sequence of `0/1` representing the number 123 in 4 bytes.

```
0b01111011
```

Isn't `"123"` the same from the **source code** perspective? Well, no. The number is surrounded by double quotes, so the compiler will interpret it as an actual string, stored in memory as a nul-terminated sequence of characters

```
--------------------------
| '1' | '2' | '3' | '\0' |
--------------------------
```

and in memory the ASCII values representing those numbers (assuming the ASCII encoding is used) will be stored

```
-----------------------------
| 0x31 | 0x32 | 0x33 | 0x00 |
-----------------------------
```

Comment: I have understood that 123 is characters for me but it is a integer for the computer. In addition to solutions, I want to know the reason from the technical aspect as much as I could understand, so your answer is very helpful. Thank you!

Comment: I need to fill the interpretation gap between computers one and my one from the usual language-like view.

Comment: @CaptainCookie is there anything still unclear in my explanation?

Comment: No, your descriving is clear! But could I ask one more question? In one comment, it is said that "'N' is an int, not a char". So although I tried to use %d printf specifier for 'N', 78 is dispalyed. Then I checked ASCII Table, which says N is 78. So although I think I understand what happens, is this behavior also useful? when can I utilize the mechanism?

Comment: @CaptainCookie let's start saying that also `char` type is an integer: an integer using just one byte so it can represent 256 values. What Tom said you is that the char literal `'N'` is promoted to type `int` (4 bytes in most platforms). Don't focus to it at the moment. Just focus on the fact that with %c you are telling the program to interpret its value like a printable character from the ascii table; with %d the program will just print its integer value.

Comment: @captaincookie knowing that characters are stored as integers can be useful as you can do algebric checks on them. It is a topic too wide for a comment; so I'll just write an example. Taking advantage of the alphabetic chars ASCII representation we can easily check that in input char is a lower case alphabetical char with a simple check like `if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z')`.

Comment: Hello, learning C programming step by step with a lot of community supports and my textbook, so I could have understood your comments and its sample. I have chacked  what you've explained with `printf("%c %d\n", '0','0');` . As your saying, the former is displayed as 0 and the latter as 48. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

> "Although `"N"` is a character, why is the `%c` specifier invalid?"

`"N"` isn't a character constant. It is a string literal. `'N'` is a character constant and matching to `%c`. The difference between single and double quotation marks is important.

Also the specifier is never invalid. Only the argument type can be.

> "Then, although I have used `%s` for `"123"`, why is it invalid?"

You did not used `"123"`, which is a string literal and emit a `char *`. You use `123`. `123` is an *integer* value stored in an object of type `int` `numbers`. An `int` argument is not permissible for the `%s` format specifier which requires an argument of type `char *`, not `int`.

That is the difference.

Comment: I have understood why my code did not work and the difference between single and double quotations is important thanks to your clear describing. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I'll go straight to your questions.

First Question:

The C programming language distinguishes between double quotes and single quotes. double quotes will create `string` literals, while single quotes will create `character` literals. So, for example `'N'` is a `character`, while `"N"` is a `string` containing only a single character, which is N. So, the reason why %c doesn't work, is that it expects a character, but you're giving it the **string** `"N"`.

Second Question:

The value of the variable `numbers` is **NOT** "123". Using the C language's notation, "123" would be a string containing the characters '1', '2', and '3', whereas the variable `numbers` contains the **integer** 123 right now, and that is the reason why %s won't work for `numbers`. Although you could convert the value of variable 123 to a string like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

main()
{
    int numbers = 123;
    char numbers_string[4];
    sprintf(numbers_string, "%d", numbers); // conversion happens here
    printf("%s\n", numbers_string); 
}
```

Also, there appears to be a confusion between the two types "string" and "character" in your question. It is important to understand that these two types are different. a character is a single Byte that (usually) holds the ASCII-code for the character you want. For example, the character `'A'` (ASCII-code = 65). But a "string" is a collection of characters, like `"Apple"`, and in the C language, a "string" is usually implemented using a `char*` which points to a location in memory that has the characters stored in sequence. (this is the reason why I used a character array to hold the results of converting `numbers` into "string")

Comment: Thank you!  Your sample code helps me understanding things.  In addition,  I've understood how to convert by sprintf. I think I can reduce choosing wrong format specifier from now on.

Answer (score 2):

> Although "N" is a character, why is %c specifier invalid?

`"N"` is a *string*, not a single character - double quotes indicate a string literal.  `'N'` (single quotes) would be a character constant<sup>1</sup>, so

```
printf( "%c\n", 'N' );
```

would work correctly.  To print `"N"`, you need to use the `%s` conversion specifier:

```
printf( "%s\n", "N" );
```

The `%s` conversion specifier expects its corresponding argument to have type `char *` (pointer to `char`), and it will tell `printf` to print the sequence of characters starting at the specified address until it sees the string terminator.

The expression `"N"` has type "2-element array of `char`" (`char [2]`), and the contents of the array are `{'N', 0}`.  In C, a string is a sequence of character values including a 0-valued terminator to mark the end of a string.  Strings (including string literals) are stored in arrays of character type.

Under most circumstances, an *expression* of type "N-element array of `T`" (`T [N]`) will be converted ("decay") to an expression of type "pointer to `T`" (`T *`) and the value of the expression will be the address of the first element of the array.

In the `printf` statement above, the expression `"N"` is converted from type `char [2]` to `char *`, and the value of the expression is the address of the first character.

> Although the value of variable "numbers" is "123", they are numbers, which are included in the character.

Let's look at the declaration of `numbers`:

```
int numbers = 123;
```

First of all, the *type* of the `numbers` variable is `int`, not `char *`.  It doesn't matter what value it contains, it is not the type that `%s` expects.   Secondly, `123` is not a string - it's not surrounded by quotes.  Instead it's an *integer* constant.

`numbers` is not a string - it's not the right type to store a string, and it doesn't contain a sequence of characters with a 0 terminator.  It's an integer, storing the binary representation of the decimal value `123`.  To print it out (that is, to produce the text representation of that integer value on your output device), you'd use `%d` or `%i`.

---

1. In C, character constants like `'N'` have type `int`, while in C++ they have type `char`.

Comment: Hello! I have learned expression like;  `char c_string[] =` but still not like `char *`. So my understanding your advice is not 100%. After learning about them, I will read your advice again. Thank you for your support!